# How to find the path of a cantilever beam's tip when it's bent?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, experimental-physics, spring

I'm trying to analyze the harmonic motion of a hacksaw blade with one end fixed to the table. I'm trying to get an equation from Hooke's Law F = kx, but I'm not sure about how to calculate the distance the tip of the beam has traveled when some force is applied to it. How can I get this?

[image]

[image]

Website: http://www.efunda.com/formulae/solid_mechanics/beams/casestudy_display.cfm?case=cantilever_endload#target

I found the equation for displacement of the tip from this website. How can I find the length of the path it takes to get from equilibrium to that point though?

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you gave more details or even a diagram. Such as where is the spring/elastic object that you are applying Hooke's Law to, how and where are you providing the force etc. I'm sure then you'd get better answers.

Comment: The analysis you provided assumes that the downward displacement of the path is tiny.  So, in that context, the length of the path is the actual length of the beam.